Tailwind styling not working correctly when extracting the code into a component Angular 16
I have a custom table styling that I reuse in different parts of my application. I want to abstract this tailwind styling code away in different angular components, but when I do it this way the styling is not applied correctly. It works correctly when I just write it out fully in the html template like this:
<table class="w-full text-sm text-left rtl:text-right text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-900">
  <thead class="text-sm text-black uppercase bg-white/50 dark:bg-white/50 dark:text-gray-900">
    <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">Firstname</th>
    ...
    <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3"></th>

  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let person of persons"
      class="bg-white/10 border-b dark:bg-white/10">
      <td class="px-6 py-4">{{person.firstname}}</td>
        ...
      <td>
        <div class="flex flex-col">
          <button mat-button color="accent">
            <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
            Edit</button>
          <button mat-button color="warn">
            <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
            Delete</button>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="bg-white/30  hover:brightness-150">
      <td colspan="9">
        <div matRipple>
          <button class="w-full h-10 " color="primary" (click)="addBetrokkene()">
            <div class="flex justify-center align-middle items-center">
              <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
              Add
            </div>
          </button>
        </div>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

Table working correctly:

However, when I try to abstract the styling away into components the styling stops working correctly. Specifically the positioning breaks down.
<thead class="text-sm text-black uppercase bg-white/50 dark:bg-white/50 dark:text-gray-900">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</thead>

<tr class="bg-white/10 border-b dark:bg-white/10">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</tr>

Table not working correctly:


You can use tailwind’s plugin function ;)

Angular encapsulates styles. This means your parent component styles will not be applied to its ng-content.
The advantage of this is it allows you to assume you are working with a fresh slate on your inner components. It isn't unlikely to assume in the future another scenario will conflict with this.
I believe it works with Tailwind because those are global styles, not affected by Angular's view encapsulation.
Ideally your styles live next to the components they are used by, or in a global stylesheet if they are truly global.

my viewencapsulation is set to none on each of these components.

Okay, good to know.
It looks like your width on your table is not 100%, appears everything else might be okay if you fix that.

Putting the width to 100% doesn't fix it, it appears the problem is that since angular puts an element around the actual html elements when they are encapsulated in a component like this: ", the table isn't parsed correctly because the thead, tr etc.. is not a direct child of the table, can't really think of a solution to this though :/

You could try content projection. https://angular.io/guide/content-projection
Your table component could have <ng-content select="[tableHeader]". Then your other component could have This is the header.
I think this might get around that. You can do the same with tableBody.
